# Не могу разобраться с записью JSON в Java объекты, Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
{  
"data":[  
  {  
     "hash":"md5:232dba893a22ac722249ad92f8bccf22",
     "id":"4f6d6dc59d1844bb80143ccc2e727a2f"
  },
  {  
     "hash":"md5:ee80acf16c48f3b659a2132526ae9800",
     "id":"a5ef4c3063d94b10a13630fa9cca90b9"
  },
  {  
     "hash":"md5:061044f40512fa72e03c2674d1539e0f",
     "id":"f58353848e744791ad72f9baf84b5734"
  }
]
}
```

Есть JSON. Не могу понять, как его засунуть в объекты. Классы я создал такие:

```
public class DataTable {

private String id;

private String hash;

public DataTable(){}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getHash() {
    return hash;
}

public void setHash(String hash) {
    this.hash = hash;
}
}
```

.

```
public class DataTableArrayList extends ArrayList<DataTable> {
        public DataTableArrayList(){}
     }
```

.

```
public class ComponentForJSON {

private DataTableArrayList data;

public ComponentForJSON(){}

public ComponentForJSON(DataTableArrayList data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public DataTableArrayList getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(DataTableArrayList data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

Считываю джейсон так:

```
private ArrayList<DataTable> readFromFileJSON(){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ComponentForJSON componentForJSON = new ComponentForJSON(new DataTableArrayList());
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile1, componentForJSON.getData().getClass());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Ошибку выдает такую

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `project.components.DataTableArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (String)"{"data": [{"hash": "md5:232dba893a22ac722249ad...
```

Вопрос: как можно это исправить и стоит ли переделывать созданные классы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataTable` - правильно сделан. А вот `ComponentForJSON` - нет, т.к. тип его переменной data должен быть просто `List<DataTable>`, свой класс создавать не надо для расширения списка. Также не нужно вручную создавать экземпляр. Делайте примерно так:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ComponentForJSON componentForJSON;
try {
    componentForJSON = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile1, componentForJSON.getClass());
    return componentForJSON.getData();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!

Comment: @user314917, пожалуйста)